# How to detect mongo router failure quickly with mongo async java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-pooling, sharding, connection-pool

If i have a pool of mongo routers in my mongo URI and if one of the mongo routers goes down abruptly, it takes some time before detecting the router is down. Which parameters to tune to enable quick detection of down mongos and hence reduce the failure time?

Note: I am using the mongo java async drivers mongo client to connect: com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClient

mongo driver version is 3.2.2 and server version is 3.4.5

Comment: *com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClient* which java driver version of mongo are you using?

Comment: mongo driver version is 3.2.2 and server version is 3.4.5